# Java %(mod) с float и double

Tags: java

Каким образом можно получать остаток от деления двух `float` или `double` примитивов? Если я использую стандартную функцию `%(mod)` она время от времени работает неправильно (из за особенностей обработки чисел с плавающей точкой, мантиссы не хватает), но мне нужны точные результаты. Есть ли в пакете java такая функция?

Comment: Слабо себе представляю как должен работать mod в случае с double float. Что значит "не правильно"?

Comment: Появляются погрешности, в результате нельзя доверять результатам условия, например (if (double % 0.1) == 0), в каких то случаях оно срабатывает, а в каких то, при полностью кратных аргументах - нет. Если логгирую (андроид), то вижу, что результат операции для двух кратных примитивов равняется, напрмер 0.0000000000001

Comment: Попробуйте использовать тип `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у вам получается что `d % 0.1 == 0.00000000001` - то виноват не оператор `%`, а оператор сравнения. **Никогда нельзя сравнивать числа с плавающей точкой на строгое равенство!**

Вот так будет работать:

```
if (d % 0.1 < eps || d % 0.1 > 0.1 - eps) ...
```

Здесь `eps` - это необходимая вам абсолютная точность. К примеру, `0.00001`

Comment: Добавлю, что в данном случае eps корректнее всего рассчитать: `eps = java.lang.Math.ulp(0.1)`. ULP означает unit in last place. Метод возвращает наименьшее число, которое можно прибавить к аргументу так, что результат будет отличаться от аргумента. То есть в данном случае `eps + 0.1` точно будет отличаться от `0.1`, а всё, что меньше — уже нет.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko это бесполезный расчет - при таком `eps` сравнение вырождается в строгое равенство, что, как известно, не работает.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko как минимум, надо брать `ulp(d)` - если считать само значение `d` вычисленным точно. Но ошибки округления могут накапливаться, так что даже `ulp(d)` - это слишком оптимистичная оценка. А если речь идет о каких-нибудь измерениях - то там уже погрешность измерения появляется, а она может быть еще больше.

Comment: Надо брать именно `ulp(0.1)` поскольку результат выражения `d % 0.1` сравним не с `d`, а с `0.1`. Что касается ошибок округления, то они справедливы для любого `eps`. Моё предложение касается того, что задание абсолютного `eps` не очень корректно, поскольку есть способ определить наименьший эпсилон для чисел, заданных в IEEE.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko вы читать умеете? Видимо, нет...

Comment: @MarkShevchenko вот вам пример: https://ideone.com/N8RDgG

Comment: предлагаю обсуждать без наездов? Я всего лишь дополнил Ваш ответ, а не сказал, что он неправилен. И даже если бы сказал — зачем столь оскорбительный тон? У нас, у программистов, истину можно выяснить на основании фактов, а не на основании того, кто знает больше обидных выражений.

Comment: Что касается Вашего примера, он доказывает, что 0.005 — более грубая оценка, чем ulp. Поэтому с такой оценкой два числа равны, в то время как с более точной — нет.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko я вам привел факт, вы его проигнорировали. Смотрите: 10000 % 0.1 - это ноль. Но при этом при наличии погрешности во входных данных ваша проверка не проходит. Так зачем она тогда нужна? На выходе должен быть детерминированный алгоритм, а не генератор случайных чисел.

Comment: В этом случае Ваш алгоритм также неверен, как и мой, поскольку при другой погрешности он также перестанет работать. Можно сказать, Вы подогнали здесь погрешность под свою точность. В данном случае, как я понимаю, предыдущая погрешность вообще к делу не относится — она может составлять например три значащих цифры после запятой, и тогда 10000 вполне может быть равным и 10046 и 10001.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko нет, я не подгонял погрешность под точность - я сделал прямо противоположное. И это - единственный адекватный способ определения `eps`. Все остальные способы будут врать.

Comment: Если так, то метод `Math.ulp` не должен иметь никакого практического смысла. То есть он "лишний" в библиотеке Java? Иными словами, если Вы задаёте абсолютную точность, зачем он вообще мог бы потребоваться?

Comment: @MarkShevchenko я не знаю, зачем он может понадобиться. Учитывая, что этого метода нет в стандартных библиотеках других языков и никто на это не жалуется - вероятно, он и правда лишний.

Comment: Он существует в C/C++ (в виде констант `DBL_EPSILON`/`FLT_EPSILON`). В.NET есть аналогичные константы у типов `double` и `float`. Главное, он существует в описании IEEE формата чисел с плавающей точкой. В действительности, он используется очень широко. Поэтому Ваши слова о том, что ваш метод является "единственным адекватным" — кажутеся не очень убедительными.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko это разные вещи. *_EPSILON - это именно что константа, которая означает минимальное по модулю число, которое в принципе способно храниться в этом типе данных. Такая константа действительно полезна на этапе валидации, или при парсинге чисел. `Math.ulp()` же - это функция. Впрочем, наверное, она тоже полезна при валидации или парсинге...

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать `BigDecimal` использовать и метод `divideAndRemainder`.

Или же найти целую часть от деления и потом вычесть:

```
int x = (int) (n / d);
result = n - d * x;
```